# JUnit: How to create a Fixture to be used in multiple JUnit Classes?

Tags: fixture

I'm wondering if it is possible to create a Test Object to be shared between multiple `JUnit` Classes. So I don't have to copy & paste *Fixtures* for multiple classes.

I have a translator object that stores mapping between language **A** and **B**. This is a common object that I used for *Processor* and *Translation Classes*.

Right now I have a Test *Fixture* at `JUnit` *Test Classes* for both `ProcessorTest` and `TranslationTest` *Classes*. E.g.

```
@Before
public void setUp()
{
  translator.add("hi","hola");
  translator.add("bye","adiós");
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the fixtures into an abstract class, and make your test classes extend this class.

Or create an implementation of a [TestRule](http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/rules/TestRule.html) and add them to each class.

You may also be able to just have a static method somewhere that creates and sets up the translator object, and call this method within the test class.